# Change Link Into Keywords with Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, text-processing

I wanna change the url text into a words, but have no idea to do that. Please help me.

Here's what I wanna do, example:

**some-text-url.html**

into

**some text url**

Comment: Will your url's always be in a hyphenated format like `some-text-url.html`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "some-text-url.html";
str = str.split('.')[0].split('-').join(' ');
```

`.split()` on the `.` gives an Array of:

```
[
    "some-text-url",
    "html"
]
```

`[0]` gives the first string in the Array `"some-text-url"`

`.split()` on the `-` gives an Array of:

```
[
    "some",
    "text",
    "url"
]
```

And `.join()` passing a string with a single space gives the final result:

```
"some text url"
```

---

Or here's another way to avoid creating an Array with `.split()`:

```
var str = "some-text-url.html";
str = str.replace(/-|\.html$/g," ");
```

Giving you `"some text url "`.

Notice the space on the end. If you don't want that, add `.slice(-1)` after the `.replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the split method:

```
var url = "some-text-url.html";
url = url.replace(".html", ""); // remove html
var words = url.split("-");

// words is now an array of the keywords
```